# Javascript not running

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I have this code here:

```
var Questions=[]
Questions[0]=["What is the answer?",["A","B","C","D"],3]
Questions[1]=["What is the answer?",["A","B","C","D"],3]
Questions[2]=["What is the answer?",["A","B","C","D"],3]
Questions[3]=["What is the answer?",["A","B","C","D"],3]

function createQuestions(id) {
    var tReturn="<form>"
    tReturn=tReturn+"<b>Questions "+id+":</b>"

    tReturn=tReturn+"</form>"
    return tReturn;
}

for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
    var elem=document.getElementById('quiz_section')
    var func=createQuestion(i)
    elem.innerHTML=elem.innerHTML+func+"<br />"
}
```

I just started using Javascript recently.  I know there must be a syntax error in here somewhere but I can't find it.  There is, in fact a DIV in the main document with an id of "quiz_selection".

I don't have access to any kind of debugger because I'm at school and almost everything is blocked.

Thanks if you can!

Comment: It is good practice to end lines with a semicolon `;`, but that cannot be the case of the syntax error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your function is named `createQuestions` but you are calling it as `createQuestion`.  Otherwise the syntax seems fine.

Additionally, if this code is embedded immediately into your page it may not function because the document will not fully exist when your for loop executes; hence the `quiz_section` div will not exist.

Enclose your loop in a function like so:

```
function initializeQuiz() {
    for (i=0;i<4;i++) {
        var elem=document.getElementById('quiz_section')
        var func=createQuestions(i)
        elem.innerHTML=elem.innerHTML+func+"<br />"
    }
}
```

And add an `onload='javascript:initializeQuiz()'` attribute to your `<BODY>` tag.

Comment: Oh, thanks!  I thought I double checked that!  --EDIT:  Actually, after doing that, it still doesn't run.

Comment: Can you be more specific about your results?

Comment: There are no results, nothing happens.  None of the code is run.  I tried inserting "alerts" as a way to judge at what point it broke but none of them show...

Comment: Modifying my answer, I think I know the problem.

Answer (score 3):

You define `createQuestions()`, however you are calling `createQuestion()`, this will naturally throw a `ReferenceError`.

Also please use semi-colons after each line. ( For good practice )

Answer (score 2):

createQuestion should be createQuestions

Answer (score 1):

You could adjust your declaration of your questions to:

```
var Questions = [
  { Question: "What is the answer?", Values: ["A", "B", "C", "D"], Answer: 3 },
  { Question: "What is the answer?", Values: ["A", "B", "C", "D"], Answer: 3 },
  { Question: "What is the answer?", Values: ["A", "B", "C", "D"], Answer: 3 },
  { Question: "What is the answer?", Values: ["A", "B", "C", "D"], Answer: 3 }
];
```

That way you can access each item as an object:

```
var question = Questions[0];
// question.Question
// question.Values
// question.Answer
```

Comment: I was unaware you could do that.  Thanks :)  POINTS FOR YOU :)

Comment: What do the {}'s mean in this case?

Comment: The `{` and `}` braces are defining a javascript object. You should have a look at Javascript Object Notation (JSON)